# How does linux kernel know which inotify_handle has a certain watch

Tags: linux, filesystems, kernel, inotify

I understood that linux kernel provides "inotify mechanism" to monitor file system.

According to inotify, `inotify_init()` returns fd to receive `inotify_event` from kernel.
(I understood kernel will write `inotify_event` on it.)

1) And if I add new watch with the `inotify fd` using `inotify_add_watch()`, Who will write `inotify_event` on inotify fd when the watched file has got an event.

2) (if kernel does,) when kernel detects an event for watched file, how does kernel decide which inotify `fd(inotify_instance)` has to update with this `inotify_event`?

Answer (score 2):

My own research, this is the answer:

1. It is linux kernel; specifically the file system.
2. When you call `inotify_add_watch()` to certain file, `inotify` stores some information of `inotify` watch into that file's `inode` structure.

Then, whenever file system deals with that file, it checks the file's `inode` sturture - whether there exists `inotify watches` or not. If `inotify` watches found from `inode` structure, `inotify` reports `inotify_event`.